# 'ask question' anonymously on security.stackexchange?

Tags: feature-request, login, anonymous, anonymous-visitors

I was thinking, perhaps after 100 reputation or something, that you should be able to post questions anonymously on [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com) kind of like the way people can on [quora.com](https://quora.com)

Then you would be able to delete or edit the question for say, 24/48 hours, but then after that, there would be no server-side trace of the question to that user's account, whether the user is logged in or logged out. And perhaps reputation is rewarded within the 24/48 hours, but not afterwards, due to it not being possible.

The reason for this is that, with the way things currently are, people could easily leave a Hansel & Gretel 'breadcrumb trail' of their security habits, actually making it easier for them to be attacked - the opposite of the intention of security.stackexchange!

On the other hand, I suppose people could simply use 'burner' accounts instead? Though I'd suppose those burner accounts would still have server side records of IP addresses, e-mails, etc. which introduces a point of failure?

I suppose I'm trying to find a solution to the issue of anonymity that a rewards based system such as Stack Exchange can facilitate.

Comment: Just ask your question from a different account. And if really necessary you have the right to be disassociated from a post. And if SE starts leaking personal details ... I'd say there is a bigger problem than just the one you try to address.